# Text sliding down from document while loading on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

My aim is to get the greeting message slide down "outside" of the page. I recently searched here for reference, and only found the cloeset code as below, but it is not what I expect because seem the text is appear in the middle of the page... Appreciate it if anyone can help me out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#greeting').hide();
    $('#greeting').slideDown(1000);
});
```

```css
#greeting { padding-top: 100px; }
```

```html
<h1 id="greeting">Welcome!</h1>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot!

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
    $("#greeting").addClass("active"); // add the class "active" to the greeting text
});
```

**CSS**:

```
#greeting{
    position: fixed; 
    top: -200px; // start at 200px above the page
    transition: top 500ms; // take 0.5s to move from -200px to 500px
} 
#greeting.active{ // when #greeting has class "active"
    top: 500px; // move to 500px from the top of the page
}
```

This approach requires the use of **CSS** along with **jQuery**, but hopefully it will suffice.

Of course, you can change the `top` property value to whatever you require, to get the desired effect.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Great! Caelan. This seem better after tweaking a bit. I will use it if using jQuery for the whole thing, but seem animate not work well with it. That's why I'm still in doubt.

Comment: @PattyPutty what is the problem you seem to be facing?